# “For nothing” = “pour rien”?

Tags: locutions

I want to translate the following:

> They don’t call it The Mile High City for nothing.

My attempt:

> On ne l’appelle pas The Mile High City pour rien.

Is that how I would translate it in this context?

Comment: It's recommended to wait 24 hrs to select an accepted answer. This gives more incentive for people to write good answers and allows time for more answers to be submitted before you choose which you prefer. It also allows the voting system to be effective and place the best answer (according to all viewers of the site) on top which can help you choose which answer to use.

Comment: as a native French speaker, it sounds correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your attempt is correct. The most idiomatic translation would still use *pour rien* but a slightly different way :

> Ce n'est pas pour rien qu'on l'appelle *The Mile High City*.

Comment: I think this expression sounds closer to the point I wanted to get across, thank you so much.

Answer (score 12):

That's it. You might also say, although it's not as literal a translation,

"Ce n'est pas sans raison qu'on l'appelle The Mile High City.", or

"Si on l'appelle The Mile High City, c'est pour une bonne raison.".

Answer (score 4):

My favorite French phrase for this is "pour des prunes," as in

> On ne l'appelle pas The Mile High City pour des prunes.

or

> Ce n'est pas pour des prunes qu'on l'appelle The Mile High City.

For reference:

[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_des_prunes)

[Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/pour-des-prunes.php)

[Axiom Cafe](https://axiomcafe.fr/pourquoi-dit-on-pour-des-prunes)

Comment: Ça me parait tellement vulgaire de nos jours que je peine à croire que l'on trouve cela dans la langue de Molière !

Comment: Interesting, I hadn’t heard of this! Thank you!

Comment: @LPH Tu as une définition bien étrange de la vulgarité...

Comment: @jlliagre Pas du tout, ce n'est pas parce que le roi Louis quatorze a pu dire de son temps "Laissez pisser le mérinos" que l'on trouve le mot "pisser" de nos jours un terme trop, trop élégant…

Comment: @LPH En quoi *prune* est il vulgaire ? PS: *Louis **XIV***, pas *Louis quatorze* qui est une marque de maroquinerie.

Comment: @jlliagre En rien tant qu'il s'agit du fruit ; en ce qui concerne l'expression c'est quelque chose que je ressens, c'est assez peu explicable ; ce n'est peu être pas un sentiment partagé par beaucoup de gens.

Comment: @LPH Tu dois être le seul. C'est une expression populaire mais elle n'a rien de vulgaire (dans le sens commun actuel de *grossier*).

Comment: Personnellement, je ne parlerai pas de vulgarité mais de péjoration. L'expression connue "Faire quelque chose pour des prunes". Il y a un sentiment de "perte de valeur" associé.
Au contraire, dans la question initiale, le "pour rien" à plutôt une connotation neutre/valorisante ("On ne m’appelle pas l'as du volant pour rien", par exemple.)

Comment: La première fois que je l'ai lu c'etait dans un livre pour enfants. J'ai présumé que ce n'était pas trop vulgaire.

Comment: Jérémy, ce n'est pas du tout vulgaire. LPH a parfois des opinions absconses...